# sqlite delete all results where column a and column b is not in first n items

Tags: sql, sqlite

Lets say I have the following table

```
a    b    c
-----------
1    1    5
1    2    3
4    1    2
1    2    4
4    2    10
```

And I want to delete all rows where none of the first n rows has the same value in a and b as that row.

So for example the resulting tables for various n's would be

n = 1

```
a    b    c
-----------
1    1    5

// No row other than the first has a 1 in a, and a 1 in b
```

n = 2

```
a    b    c
-----------
1    1    5
1    2    3
1    2    4

// The fourth row has the same values in a and b as the second, so it is not deleted. The first 2 rows of course match themselves so are not deleted
```

n = 3

```
a    b    c
-----------
1    1    5
1    2    3
4    1    2
1    2    4

// The fourth row has the same values in a and b as the second, so it is not deleted. The first 3 rows of course match themselves so are not deleted
```

n = 4

```
a    b    c
-----------
1    1    5
1    2    3
4    1    2
1    2    4 

// The first 4 rows of course match themselves so are not deleted. The fifth row does not have the same value in both a and b as any of the first 4 rows, so is deleted.
```

I've been trying to work out how to do this using a not in or a not exists, but since I'm interested in two columns matching not just 1 or the whole record, I'm struggling.

Comment: what is the order by criterion? is n =  ID?

Comment: It's irrelevant - I just want to get a smaller collection of data to make it more workable, but I need to have all the data for any given a together with b for it to be valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not defining a specific order, the result is not completely defined, but depends on arbitrary choices of implementation regarding which rows are computed first in the limit clause. A different SQLite version for example may give you a different result. With that being said, I believe that you want the following query:

```
select t1.* from table1 t1, 
(select distinct t2.a, t2.b from table1 t2 limit N) tabledist 
where t1.a=tabledist.a and t1.b=tabledist.b;
```

where you should replace N with the desired number of rows

EDIT: So, to delete directly from the existing table you need something like:

```
with toremove(a, b, c) as 
    (select * from table1 tt 
    EXCEPT select t1.* from table1 t1, 
    (select distinct t2.a, t2.b from table1 t2 limit N) tabledist 
    where t1.a=tabledist.a and t1.b=tabledist.b) 
delete from table1 where exists 
(select * from toremove 
where table1.a=toremove.a and table1.b=toremove.b and table1.c=toremove.c);
```

Comment: That worked great thanks. I believe that including c in the second part is unnecessary though